# Ionic 2 Angularfire2 - add list of objects from database to FirebaseListObservable

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm trying to display a list of objects in my Firebase Database, but I am having a hard time to add the objects to the FirebaseListObservable.

Here is my code:

```
    products: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

    this.db.list('products/' + this.user.uid, { preserveSnapshot: true})
                .subscribe(snapshots=>{
                  var jsonObject = [];
                  snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
                    jsonObject.push(snapshot.val());
                  });
                  this.products = jsonObject;
    });
```

The error I get is that I can't assigne any[] to a FirebaseListObservable.

This is my HTML:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item class="text" *ngFor="let product of products | async">
      {{product}}
    </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

My database looks like this:

[image: Thanks in advanced for the help :)]

Comment: `this.db.list` this returns Observables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your **products** is **FirebaseListObservable**, however, your **jsonObject** is an array, so you can't let **this.products = jsonObject**

maybe you should do like the following:

```
products: Observable<any[]>;
this.products = this.db.list('products/' + this.user.uid, { preserveSnapshot: true})
            .map(snapshots=>{
             return snapshots.map(snapshot => {
                return snapshot.val();
              });
});
```

Comment: I tried to implement your solution, but I couldnt see any products in my html page

Comment: in your .ts file, use the following code to print the array at first, to check if the array exists:
`this.products.subscribe((items)=>console.log(items))`

you can add this code in ngOnInit() method

Comment: my bad, had a typing mistake in my HTML. It works now :) thank you for the answer!